# substitute string when there is a dot + number + ':'

Tags: r, string-substitution

I have strings that look like these:

```
> ABCD.1:f_HJK
> ABFD.1:f_HTK
> CJD:f_HRK
> QQYP.2:f_HDP
```

So basically, I have always a string in the first part, I could have a part with . and a number, and after this part I always have ':' and a string.
I would like to remove the '. + number' when it is included in the string, using R.

I know that maybe regular expressions could be useful but I have not idea about I can apply them in this context. I know that I can substitute the '.' with gsub, but not idea about how I can add the information about number and ':'.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: what is your expected end results?

Comment: `gsub("[.]\\d+(?=:)", "", vec, perl=TRUE)`

Answer (score 0):

Does this work:

```
v <- c('ABCD.1:f_HJK','ABFD.1:f_HTK','CJD:f_HRK','QQYP.2:f_HDP')
v
[1] "ABCD.1:f_HJK" "ABFD.1:f_HTK" "CJD:f_HRK"    "QQYP.2:f_HDP"
gsub('([A-Z]{,4})(\\.\\d)?(:.*)','\\1\\3',v)
[1] "ABCD:f_HJK" "ABFD:f_HTK" "CJD:f_HRK"  "QQYP:f_HDP"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use any of the following depending on the structure of your string

- If no other period and numbers in the string

  ```
   sub("\\.\\d+", "", v)
   [1] "ABCD:f_HJK" "ABFD:f_HTK" "CJD:f_HRK"  "QQYP:f_HDP"
  ```
- If you are only interested in the first pattern matched.

  ```
   sub("^([A-Z]+)\\.\\d+:", "\\1:", v)
   [1] "ABCD:f_HJK" "ABFD:f_HTK" "CJD:f_HRK"  "QQYP:f_HDP"
  ```
- Same as above, invoking perl. ie no captured groups

  ```
    sub("^[A-Z]+\\K\\.\\d+", "", v, perl = TRUE)
    [1] "ABCD:f_HJK" "ABFD:f_HTK" "CJD:f_HRK"  "QQYP:f_HDP"
  ```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your explanation correctly, this should do the trick:

```
gsub("(\\.\\d+)", "", string)
```